# How to incorporate Google Analytics Event Tracking with Anythingslider

Tags: google-analytics, anythingslider

I am looking for some clues on where to add [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) [Event Tracking](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html) to a page that has [AnythingSlider](http://css-tricks.com/anythingslider-jquery-plugin/) installed. I have a slider that does not autoscroll and you have to click the navigation buttons for the slides to move. I wish to track these clicks. I would also like to track if a visitor clicks on a link within a slide.

I am wishing to use Google's [InPage Analytics](http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=178902) to track visitor click behavior and workout what items (images & phrases) catch the attention of the visitor in order to make better lead funnels.

I did try the Event tracking guide from Google before posting here, but I was unsure of where to pickup the navigation clicks from the slider.

Comment: Have you tried adding jQuery click handlers for the arrows and firing the event there?

Answer (score 0):

add this to any a href in your html

```
  onClick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Slider','Panelno:x', 'blah']);"
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested (I'm about to do this myself) but the API suggests to me that  I should use the `onSlideComplete` callback, e.g. (assuming you've set up the names of your panels in an array called pages).

```
onSlideComplete     : function(foo) {
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Slider','Panelno:'+slider.currentPage, pages[index - 1]]);
}
```

EDIT: Be careful with `onSlideComplete`, it seems to fire off too often. Set a var to tell it not to refire, and reset the var with `onSlideBegin`.

```
onSlideBegin     : function(e, slider) {
    refire = 1;
},
onSlideComplete     : function(slider) {
    if (refire) {
        _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Slider','Panelno:'+slider.currentPage, pages[slider.currentPage - 1]]);
        refire=0;
    }
}
```